# Book about ethereal witches that interact with humans

Tags: story-identification, books

This is a book I read nearly 30 years ago and my memory is hazy.

I remember that there were three witches, all sisters, who had no real physical form, yet managed to interact with people.

There was one witch who was more in charge than the others, she seemed to be the leader.

One was fat, one was sexual?

One of the key scenes I remember was one of the witches seduced the main character (strange because they had no real physical body) and she was described as feeling cold. Physically cold.

This particular witch would *spawn*, I am pretty sure that is the vernacular they used, offspring, that were also hazy and black in appearance.

There was far more to the story line, but I am getting hard pressed to remember the whole story line.

Comment: Please let me know if this is too hazy, more of the plot might come to me

Comment: Three sister witches is a very common theme.  You might see this article http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheHecateSisters and see if any of the examples given ring a bell.  Other than that, it would probably take more details for anyone to pin it down.

Comment: @ChrisSunami I found it thanks to your link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @Chris Sunami's link prompting memories and giving me a lead to search I found the book.

Weaveworld, by Clive Barker, published in 1987.

The three sisters:

> - [Immacolata:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaveworld) A cold, ruthless sorceress, who was exiled by her own race for practising evil magic and desiring too much power. A woman of tremendous dark abilities, she seeks the rug with the purpose of destroying it and ultimately unmaking her kind.
> - The Hag: one of Immacolata's triplet sisters, whom she strangled while all three were in the womb. The Hag survived as the ghostly presence of a gruesome old woman, always accompanying her sister and helping her when necessary. She can divine knowledge by examining the afterbirth produced by her prolific and likewise ghostly sister.
> - The Magdalene: Immacolata's other triplet sister who also survives after her prenatal death as ectoplasm. She frequently rapes defenceless men and gives birth to brutally deformed abominations (called by-blows) within hours of their conception.

Comment: No wonder I was confused two of the three sister's were dead!

Comment: Seriously, weaveworld makes me think of looms or silkworms